# How to return values over multiple functions, or declare a function implicit?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct, tic-tac-toe

Im currently making a TicTacToe and Im passing 2 values through several functions. After the functions, I need the value to be returned to the main() function, or call the first function (here it is named 'eingabe'. Sadly, I dont know, how to pass 2 values over 4 functions or how to call a "yet undeclared" function.

Here you can see my Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char spielfeld(char symbol[3][3], int counter){ 
    printf("\n");
    for(int i=0; i<4;i++){
        for(int j =0; j<3;j++){
            printf("+---");
        }
        printf("+\n");
        if(i<3){
            for(int k=0; k<3;k++){
                if(symbol[i][k]== 0){
                    symbol[i][k]=" ";
                }
                printf("| %c ", symbol[i][k]);
            }
            printf("|  ");
        printf("%d\n",i);
        }
    }
    printf("  A   B   C\n");
    counter = counter +1;
    eingabe(counter, symbol);
    return(symbol, counter);
}

char symbolset(int auswahl[2], char* spieler, char symbol[3][3], int counter){
    for(int i=0; i<3;i++){
        for(int j=0; j<3;j++){
            if(auswahl[0]==i && auswahl[1]==j){
                symbol[i][j]= *spieler;
            }
            else{
                symbol[i][j]=0;
            }
        }
    }
    spielfeld(symbol, counter);
    return(symbol, counter);

}

char umwandlung(char* eingabe, char* spieler, char symbol[3][3], int counter){
    int auswahl[2];
    char* chara="aa";
    char* charb="bb";
    if(eingabe[1]==48){
        auswahl[0]=0;
    }
    else if (eingabe[1]==49)
    {
        auswahl[0]=1;
    }
    else{
        auswahl[0]=2;
    }
    if(eingabe[0]==chara[0]){
        auswahl[1]=0;
    }
    else if (eingabe[0]==charb[0])
    {
        auswahl[1]=1;
    }
    else{
        auswahl[1]=2;
    }
    symbolset(auswahl, spieler, symbol, counter);
    return(symbol, counter);
}

char eingabe(int counter, char symbol[3][3]){
    char* spieler = "X";
    if(counter%2==0){
        spieler = "X";
    }
    else{
        spieler = "O";
    }
    int auswahl[2];
    char* eingabe= calloc(2, sizeof(char));
    scanf("%s", eingabe);
    printf("%d", eingabe[1]);
    umwandlung(eingabe, spieler, symbol, counter);
    return(symbol, counter);
}

int main(){
    int counter = 0;
    char symbol[3][3];
    printf("%d,%c",eingabe(counter, symbol));
    eingabe(counter, symbol);
    printf("%d,%c",eingabe(counter, symbol));
    
}
```

I tried already using a struct, but I still would need to pass it through all the functions, right? Any advices are welcome :) Thanks already

Comment: Ive also thought about using pointers, but I dont know, if the adresses of 'counter' and 'symbol' stay the same? could i just recall them after the 'eingabe(counter, symbol)' in the main() function?

Comment: Why would you want to call a "yet undeclared function"? Why not declare it?

Comment: Its already declared, but below the function that calls it. The 'spielfelf' function needs to call the 'eingabe' fucntion. but because its below the other, I cant call it. But because the 'eingabe' function needs to call the 'umwandlung', I cant just put 'eingabe' on top.

Comment: `return(symbol, counter);` won't do what you may think. If you pass `counter` as a pointer you can modify it inside the function. What have you tried "using a struct"? What does your compiler have to say about the posted code?

Comment: Modify it in which function? In the first function it its returned to, or can I return it as a counter through all functions?

Comment: I'm actually having an hard time trying to follow the logic of this program (not only because of the variable and functions name). Why have you come up with this pattern of calling a different function just before the return of any function?

Comment: Let's start with `spielfeld`, what's its purpose? If it has to print the board, then make it *just* print the board and nothing else. It shouldn't modify any passed variable nor call any other function unless they are *needed* to accomplish its task. It also doesn't really need to return anything (unless you want to check things like how many chars were printed).

Comment: If the function is defined after the place where you call it, it is not declared. That's it. Declare it before you use it. Just provide a function prototype before you use the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Return a `struct`

Close to OP's request.

```
typedef struct {
  char symbol[3][3];
  int counter;
} ttt;


ttt spielfeld(char symbol[3][3], int counter) { 
  ttt t;
  ...
  return t;
}
// or 
ttt spielfeld(ttt state) { 
// or 
ttt spielfeld(ttt *state) {
```

---

2. Pass in the location to save the new state as a `struct *`.

This is more C idiomatic.

```
// Perhaps return an error flag should something go wrong
bool spielfeld(ttt *new_state, char symbol[3][3], int counter) { 
// or 
bool spielfeld(ttt *new_state, ttt *old_state) {
```